# XNA framework component in WP7 App?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, marketplace

I wanted to re-confirm this doubt i have. Is there still no way to exit an app decently??? I mean without raising and catching an exception.Because recently, I read [HERE](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/92018/551387.aspx) that now we can use XNA Framework APIs in our app, so is Game.Exit() valid now. Using it will result in passing the App certification?

Thanks,
Apoorva :)

Comment: Why do you want to force the app to close?

Comment: Pretty sure you wont pass submission. Phone apps are NEVER meant to be killed. Just tombstoned.

Comment: The back key press isn't exiting the app.. Thats the reason i need an alternative...

Comment: Without knowing why the back key isn't working, it's difficult to advise -- have you overridden its behaviour in any way? (see also [5.2.4 of the technical requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840%28v=vs.92%29))

Comment: Actually.. No... Tats the reason am not able to figure out what the problem is..

Comment: Have you checked what code is running after you *should* have exited? It would obviously be better to fix the cause, rather than put something in place that may cause other problems